# Open excel file using PHPExcel and save it to a folder

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to make a PHP file to run online (e.g. http://www.writephponline.com/ and alternatively I can use PUTTY). This script will get an excel file from a link. Then it will save it to a folder (given link). It seems that there is an error.

```
include 'my_link/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$inputFileName = 'FILE_NAME';

$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007;
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$workbook =  $reader->load($file);

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($workbook, 'Excel2007'); 
$objWriter->save('FOLDER_NAME'); 

exit();
```

The error is :

01) Class 'PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007' not found

UPD:

I even tried that :

```
require_once('apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/IOFactory.php'); 
require_once('apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/Excel2007.php');

$fileType=PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify("FILE.xlsx");
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader("Excel2007");

$objReader->setReadDataOnly(true);   
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load("FILE.xlsx");
$objWriter->save("http://apolosiskos.co.uk/output.xlsx");
```

and I got :

02) PHPExcel_IOFactory

I have included the source though and I don't know why it is not working. Is there a public link for PHPExcel.php so I can test?

Comment: Are you using any autoloader script for your own code? If so, then it could be clashing with PHPExcel's autoloader

Comment: @MarkBaker That's all I have in my script. Nothing else. I am trying to run the file online http://phpfiddle.org/ and http://www.writephponline.com/

Comment: Then tough! There is no way you can include the entirety of PHPExcel via a remote url at runtime, and I don't know any PHP libraries/frameworks that permit that

Comment: Like most/all PHP libraries, PHPExcel expects you to have downloaded the library and to have it locally on the same server as the rest of your code

Comment: Yo might conceivably be able to do this if you included a phar file via a link, I guess that's possible, though I've never tried it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively you can read your file like this;

```
$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReaderForFile($inputFileName);
$reader->setReadDataOnly(true);
$workbook = $reader->load($inputFileName);
```

Unless you have special reason for choosing to use `PHPExcel_Reader_Excel2007`

Comment: The problem hints in the PHPExcel. it says "Class 'PHPExcel_IOFactory' not found".

Comment: This could be as a result of namespace. Add `use PHPExcel_IOFactory`

Comment: I added that :
require_once('apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/PHPExcel.php'); require_once('apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/IOFactory.php'); require_once('apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/Excel2007.php');

Comment: I mean use the namespace `PHPExcel_IOFactory` explicitly after requiring the appropriate files. After the `require_once` statements just before your class/method declaration add the statement `use PHPExcel_IOFactory`

Answer (score 0):

You can't require fully qualified php files from a server, it expects a file.

Right now your require is just getting the output of the files you are including, as it is making a request to that URL.

Comment: Did it :
require_once('http://apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/PHPExcel.php');
require_once('http://apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/IOFactory.php');
require_once('http://apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/Excel2007.php');

Comment: But still I am getting an error :
require_once(http://apolosiskos.co.uk/Classes/IOFactory.php): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error -- at line 22

Comment: I noticed you are using full qualified urls on your require, updating my asnwer

Comment: Yes. 100%. I do not know why the links do not open.

Comment: So, isn't there a public link that will load this libraries?

Comment: `So, isn't there a public link that will load this libraries?` Not at run time via a URL, no.... I'm not aware of any PHP Libraries that provide that option; you need to have downloaded the library to your server, and include it locally

Comment: @MarkBaker The file will run in PUTTY or any other online PHP compiler. I need to have include the 'PHPExcel.php' by using a link. I have put all files on my server and still not working. Where should I save the files and call it in the PHP file?

Comment: You have to refer to them from disk paths, like /var/www/yourproject/library/PHPExcel/Autoloader.php, see http://php.net/manual/es/function.getcwd.php